# fatal: Not a git repository: '.'

Tags: linux, git

I have a valid `git` repository named `/tmp/A`.
When I `cd` to the `/tmp/A` and run any `git` command from bash it works good, but when I run `git` commands from `callCommand` call in haskell programm I get error:

```
fatal: Not a git repository: '.'
```

If I run in `callCommand` `pwd` and `ls -la` before `git` command, like:

```
callCommand $ "pwd; ls -la; git status"
```

It shows that it is at right path `/tmp/A` and `ls` shows that repository exists and has `.git` directory, but git returns error.

What wrong I do?

**Upd.**

`ls` output is

```
drwxrwxr-x 11 xxx xxx 4096 Mar 22 11:44 .
drwxrwxr-x  3 xxx xxx 4096 Mar 22 11:44 ..
drwxrwxr-x  8 xxx xxx 4096 Mar 22 11:44 .git
-rw-rw-r--  1 xxx xxx  270 Mar 22 11:44 .gitignore
drwxrwxr-x  7 xxx xxx 4096 Mar 22 11:44 dir2
drwxrwxr-x  8 xxx xxx 4096 Mar 22 11:44 dir1
drwxrwxr-x  9 xxx xxx 4096 Mar 22 11:44 test
```

**Upd. Upd.**

Program which fails is called from hook `post-receive` of cloned git repository. When run same program not from hook of this repository, it works fine.
Why self cloning repository from hook does not works?

Comment: What exactly does `ls -la` outputs?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen, updated

Comment: can you do a `git fsck --full` to check if your `.git` folder looks good ?

Comment: Can you try `GIT_TRACE = 1; git status` as well?

Comment: @user2599522 both commands above returns same error: `fatal: Not a git repository: '.'`

Comment: then your `.git` folder is screwed i think. Does it contain anything ? `find .git/ -type f`

Comment: Double check if your git repository is indeed valid instead of just assuming it - that seems the most likely culprit here

Comment: @user2599522, This repository is cloned by command called from `post-receive` of this repo, can it bring this problem?

Comment: I am no git expert, but it seems that you invoke `git`, which executes the `post-receive` action, which tries to run another `git` process while the repo is still in use by the first `git`. This is sometimes called a "reentrance issue": I would not expect `git` to be reentrant and to allow calling `git` itself from its triggered scripts.

Comment: If the program itself works fine but doesn't work being called from `post-receive` verify your environment variables, especially `GIT_DIR` and `GIT_WORK_TREE`.

Comment: @phd, setting `GIT_DIR` properly resolved problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: you probably want `unset GIT_DIR` at the front of your script (well, however Haskell spells this operation).

---

The issue here is that while `/tmp/A` *is* a sensible Git repository, the actual *repository itself* is in the `.git` sub-directory.  That is, `/tmp/A/` is the *work-tree* and `/tmp/A/.git` is the *repository proper*.

In normal operation, we run `git subcommand arguments ...`, e.g., `git status` or `git commit -m message` from our *work-trees*.  The work-tree contains a `.git` directory or, in some cases,<sup>1</sup> a `.git` file.  The top-level `git` command checks for `.git`, finds it, and says *aha, the **repository** is `./.git`*.  Or, it does not find `.git`, so it looks one level up—e.g., from `/tmp/A` it would climb one level to `/tmp` itself, and check there for `.git`.  This repeats until some sort of stopping point.<sup>2</sup>

In all cases, this search process *must* either stop successfully—by finding the repository proper—or else `git subcommand` dies with the `fatal: Not a git repository ...` message.  Now comes the critical, and hidden in plain sight, secret: **At this point, the top-level `git` command sets an environment variable named `GIT_DIR` to contain the path name of the actual repository.**  It then runs the sub-command, which uses `$GIT_DIR` to locate the repository.  In our normal use-case, where we are in `/tmp/A` and `/tmp/A` contains a `.git` directory, this sets `$GIT_DIR` to `/tmp/A/.git` and the sub-commands all work.

But in your case, **`$GIT_DIR` is already set.**  Specifially, it's set to `.`.  So now the top-level `git` command *stops searching*.  It just verifies that `$GIT_DIR` is valid and names a Git repository, or dies with the `fatal` error message.  Since `/tmp/A` *isn't* a repository—it's really `/tmp/A/.git`—this causes the problem.

Unsetting the environment variable turns the search back on, fixing the problem.  You can also use `--git-dir` as an argument, or set a correct value in `$GIT_DIR`.  Note that the same rules apply with `$GIT_WORK_TREE`: the `--work-tree` argument sets `$GIT_WORK_TREE`, and if you don't use that and `$GIT_WORK_TREE` *isn't* set, the front-end `git` command uses its *climb up the file system tree to a `.git` directory or file* code to find the root of your work-tree.  So if `$GIT_DIR` or `$GIT_WORK_TREE` *are* set when you run `git subcommand`, Git obeys them unless you override them with `--git-dir` and/or `--work-tree`.

Hooks always have `$GIT_DIR` set.  They may or may not have `$GIT_WORK_TREE` set as well.  Most of them run in the top level of the work-tree, but, as [the githooks documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks/) notes, `pre-receive`, `update`, `post-receive`, `post-update`, and `push-to-checkout` all run in `$GIT_DIR`.

---

<sup>1</sup>The `.git`-as-a-file trick is used by both submodules and added work-trees, in modern Git.  Git 1.7 and early 1.8 left submodules with embedded `.git` directories, and does not support added work-trees.

<sup>2</sup>The obvious stopping point is upon reaching `/`, when there is nowhere left to climb.  However, Git is by default careful, at least on Unix and Unix-like systems, to avoid climbing through a *mount point*.  Mount points allow you to graft different file system layers and/or storage pools into a single tree-structured hierarchy.  Typically `/tmp` itself might be a memory file system, for instance, and large systems might isolate "system storage" (`/` and the like) from "user storage" (`/home`).  Docker uses mount points to restructure file systems in the docker image, and so on.