# git -C funny business: fatal: a git repository

Tags: linux, git

In the home dir, I create a bare git repo

`git init --bare repo.git`

and a regular repo
`mkdir dir1`
`cd dir1`
`git init`
`touch file1`
`git add file1`
`git commit`
and everything works fine.

And also when I run the same commands with `git -C dir1` from the home dir.
So all is good and well, right?

Also, when I am inside of 'dir1', I can `clone --mirror` it into the bare repo
`cd dir1`
`git clone --mirror ../repo1.git`

**The problem**:

From the home dir, I want to `clone --mirror` dir1
`cd ~`
`git -C dir1 clone --mirror repo1.git`

**get an error**:
fatal: 'repo.git/' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

How could I do this?

P.S.

I looked at discussions such as:
[fatal: does not appear to be a git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7318918/fatal-does-not-appear-to-be-a-git-repository)
and
[fatal: Not a git repository: '.'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55298204/fatal-not-a-git-repository)
but they do not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

According to [git](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt--Cltpathgt)

> -C path
>
> Run as if git was started in path instead of the current working directory.

That means, you need to specified, that your bare repository `repo1.git` is in the parent directory. So just run:
`git -C dir1 clone --mirror ../repo1.git`